# duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Reachability

Tags: ios

I have added TurnOutNow library which contain EASDK.h and libEventAnalytics.a

My project & TurnOutNow library  have reachability.m file.

So it is giving following errror on build :

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Reachability in:
>       /Users/achavan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Meeting_Caddie-bbzedidjjyellubhnftrohiumzog/Build/Intermediates/Meeting
>   Caddie.build/Debug-iphoneos/Meeting
>   Caddie.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Reachability.o
>       /Work_Theme_iPhone/New M_Caddie/Eventpedia_Beta/iOS_Eventpedia/TurnOutNow_SDK/libEventAnalytics.a(Reachability.o)
>   ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7

I searched on stackoverflow and found that removing reachability.m from build phases would work.

But it is giving following error:

> (null): "_kReachabilityChangedNotification", referenced from:
>
> (null): -[AppDelegate setUpRechability] in AppDelegate.o
>
> (null): +[ASIHTTPRequest registerForNetworkReachabilityNotifications]
>   in ASIHTTPRequest.o
>
> (null): +[ASIHTTPRequest
>   unsubscribeFromNetworkReachabilityNotifications] in ASIHTTPRequest.o
>
> (null): Symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>
> (null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Please let me know how I can solve this issue.

I renamed reachability class.It is working fine on device.
But giving following error when I build on IOS simulator.
   (null): Ignoring file /Work_Theme_iPhone/New M_Caddie/MeetingCaddie/iOS_Eventpedia/TurnOutNow_SDK/libEventAnalytics.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Work_Theme_iPhone/New M_Caddie/MeetingCaddie/iOS_Eventpedia/TurnOutNow_SDK/libEventAnalytics.a (2 slices)

(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EASDK", referenced from:

EASDK is a file in imported external library. Any help appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try to change the name of your .m file.

Comment: @Akeara filename doesn't matter

Comment: I changed name of file. It is working fine on device.

Comment: But giving following error when I build on IOS simulator.                                   (null): Ignoring file /Work_Theme_iPhone/New M_Caddie/MeetingCaddie/iOS_Eventpedia/TurnOutNow_SDK/libEventAnalytics.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Work_Theme_iPhone/New M_Caddie/MeetingCaddie/iOS_Eventpedia/TurnOutNow_SDK/libEventAnalytics.a (2 slices)

(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EASDK", referenced from:

EASDK is a file in imported external library. Any help appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If yours and `TurnOutNow` `Reachability` are the same, just remove it from your project's `target` and leave only header file, that will links fine. But if they are different ones, add prefix to your own interface. Looks like you have the second case